# Clean way of calling method on each item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

Is there a better way of calling a method on each item in an array than:

```
_.each(items, function(item) {
    item.method();
});
```

In Scala, you can do something like:

```
items.foreach(_.method())
```

was wondering if there's something similar in javascript

Comment: a clean one liner would be nice

Comment: _"a clean one liner would be nice "_ ? `js` at Question could be placed on one line . Is requirement to not use a library ?

Comment: yes but it won't be clean :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is tagged with Underscore, it has a nice utility method : [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) :

```
_.invoke(items, 'method')
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try using the [built-in foreach](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array.prototype.forEach)?

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.method();
});
```

Browser support is [pretty much ubiquitous](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Array.prototype.forEach) by now.

Comment: Kevin, next time please add the code along with the question.

Comment: while true, it's better than including an entire library (underscore in this case) to do something already built into the language.

Comment: In ES6, you can do `items.forEach( item => item.method() );`

Answer (score 3):

Is it the anonymous function that you don't like? I find that much more readable than this answer, but if you really want to avoid it, and every item shares the same `method` through a prototype, and you know there is at least one item, you can do this to avoid it:

```
_.each( items, items[0].method.call );
```

In ES6 you can also use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
_.each( items, item => item.method() );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use some of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) functions, I'll give you the way kind of functional approach.

```
_.each(items, _.method('method'));
```

[_.method](https://lodash.com/docs#method)

Comment: Nice, your solution and @nikoshr's answer are definitely "cleaner" than mine.

Comment: Thanks. But, I've just realized @vic tagged `Underscore.js`. edit: oh, he added `lodash` too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `for` loop

```
for (var i=0;i<items.length;items[i++].method());
```

```js
var items = [{
  method: function() {
    console.log(0)
  }
}, {
  method: function() {
    console.log(1)
  }
}];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; items[i++].method());
```